# RandomAccessFile from asset,raw,etc. folder file

Tags: android

I want to use RandomAccessFile in my app and one of the requirenment is to keep my files inside app. So I'm able to read files from resouces, but in case of using RandomAccessFile I need String or File instance to work with it.

And As I know Is not possible to get absolute path of asset file or of file in raw folder. Maybe some workaround solution is here? How to read resource file using RandomAccessFile?

Comment: AFAIK, that's not an option.